# Unable to install any rpm package in AIX after removing some packages

Tags: rpm, aix

We have an AIX 6.1 server which was working; it does not have most of the freeware packages:

```
root@srv/ins:rpm -qa
cdrecord-1.9-7
mkisofs-1.13-4
vnc-3.3.3r2-6
openssl-0.9.7l-2
unzip-5.51-1
bash-4.2-3
AIX-rpm-6.1.8.15-12
```

We needed node.js, so I tried to install its dependencies from bullfreeware.com website using the `rpm -ivh` command. Finally, I got the `node` program working at this state:

```
root@srv/ins:rpm -qa
cdrecord-1.9-7.ppc
mkisofs-1.13-4.ppc
AIX-rpm-6.1.8.15-29.ppc
gdbm-1.12-1.ppc
bzip2-1.0.6-3.ppc
libffi-3.2.1-3.ppc
libstdc++-devel-6.3.0-2.ppc
info-6.4-1.ppc
sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
mpfr-3.1.2-3.ppc
gcc-cpp-6.3.0-2.ppc
gcc-c++-6.3.0-2.ppc
ca-certificates-2017.07.17-1.ppc
rsync-3.1.3-2.ppc
gettext-0.19.8.1-3.ppc
openssl-1.1.0g-1withsslv2.ppc
python-2.7.16-1.ppc
libidn-1.24-1.ppc
openldap-2.4.46-1.ppc
xz-libs-5.2.4-1.ppc
libunistring-0.9.9-2.ppc
libICE-1.0.8-1.ppc
shared-mime-info-1.6-1.ppc
libpng-1.6.27-2.ppc
libtiff-4.0.6-2.ppc
vim-common-7.4-4.ppc
pixman-0.34.0-1.ppc
fontconfig-2.11.95-2.ppc
atk-2.20.0-2.ppc
xcb-proto-1.12-1.ppc
libX11-1.6.3-1.ppc
libXrandr-1.4.2-1waixX11.ppc
unzip-5.51-1.ppc
bash-4.2-3.ppc
vnc-3.3.3r2-6.ppc
libgcc-6.3.0-2.ppc
perl-5.28.1-1.ppc
expat-2.2.6-1.ppc
libstdc++-6.3.0-2.ppc
ncurses-6.1-2.ppc
readline-8.0-1.ppc
zlib-1.2.11-1.ppc
gmp-6.1.2-1.ppc
libmpc-1.0.3-1.ppc
gcc-6.3.0-2.ppc
grep-3.1-1.ppc
db-6.2.32-2.ppc
less-487-1.ppc
glib2-2.56.1-2.ppc
libssh2-1.8.0-1.ppc
libiconv-1.14-1.ppc
cyrus-sasl-2.1.26-3.ppc
curl-7.64.0-1ldapssl.ppc
libxml2-2.9.7-1.ppc
libyaml-0.1.7-1.ppc
libSM-1.2.1-1.ppc
libjpeg-9b-2.ppc
jbigkit-libs-2.0-3.ppc
gdk-pixbuf-2.35.1-1waixX11.ppc
freetype2-2.4.4-3.ppc
lzo-2.10-1.ppc
harfbuzz-1.2.6-1.ppc
pkg-config-0.25-3.ppc
libxcb-1.12-1waixX11.ppc
libXrender-0.9.9-1.ppc
root@srv:/opt/freeware/bin/node app.js
```

... but `npm` would not work because of the git package, and git needs another version of gettext package, and gettext was a dependency of a lot of packages including AIX-rpm-6.1.8.15-30.ppc. I started using `rpm -e` to remove its dependents to install them after that; my last commands was:

```
root@srv/ins:rpm -e sqlite
root@srv/ins:rpm -e readline
error: Failed to initialize NSS library
```

after this point I was unable to install anything! Here is the error:

```
root@srv/ins:rpm -ivh sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc.rpm
error: Failed dependencies:
    libc.a(shr.o) is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    libc.a(shr_64.o) is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    libgcc >= 6.3.0 is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    libgcc_s.a(shr.o) is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    libncurses.a(libncurses.so.6) is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    libpthread.a(shr_xpg5.o) is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    libpthread.a(shr_xpg5_64.o) is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    libreadline.a(libreadline.so.7) is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    libz.a(libz.so.1) is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    ncurses >= 6.1 is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    readline >= 7.0-5 is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
    zlib is needed by sqlite-3.27.1-1.ppc
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Also, I just want to make sure you're aware of IBM's RPM repository at https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/aix-toolbox/alpha.html

Comment: yes some of packages are from aix-toolbox but ie. openssl is not there and I was forced to use bullfreeware.com

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the issue

1-Download rpm.rte package from ibm site and execute:

```
 installp -aXYF -d /path/to/rpm/rpm_rte rpm.rte
```

2-Download full gcc zip package for aix6.1(94mb) from bullfreeware.com and extract it in folder and install it using

```
rpm -Uvh *rpm
```

3-Download full git zip package excluding the packages installed in last step(130mb) and install it like step 2 and execute this:

```
export LIBPATH=/opt/freeware/lib64:/opt/freeware/lib:/usr/lib
```

4-Download and install cpio from bullfreeware.com and follow steps related to 2018-January 17th to fix libintl.so.9 issue like this:

```
rpm2cpio gettext-0.19.8-1.aix6.1.ppc.rpm | /opt/freeware/bin/cpio -iv opt/freeware/lib/libintl.a 
--> opt/freeware/lib/libintl.a 
# ar xv opt/freeware/lib/libintl.a libintl.so.9 
x - libintl.so.9 
# ar q /opt/freeware/lib/libintl.a libintl.so.9 
# ar -X64 xv opt/freeware/lib/libintl.a libintl.so.9 
x - libintl.so.9 
# ar -X64 q /opt/freeware/lib/libintl.a libintl.so.9
```

I have installed cdrecord, vnc and mkisofs , just because they were installed last time. Final query on rpm was like this:

```
root@srv:/ins>rpm -qa
cdrecord-1.9-7.ppc
libgcc-8.3.0-1.ppc
libstdc++-8.3.0-1.ppc
mpfr-3.1.4-1.ppc
libmpc-1.0.3-2.ppc
libffi-3.2.1-2.ppc
libxml2-2.9.4-2.ppc
libiconv-1.14-22.ppc
bash-4.4-4.ppc
gcc-8.3.0-1.ppc
vnc-3.3.3r2-6.ppc
mkisofs-1.13-4.ppc
db-4.8.24-4.ppc
perl-5.28.0-1.ppc
expat-2.2.6-1.ppc
sqlite-3.7.15.2-3.ppc
rsync-3.1.2-3.ppc
unixODBC-2.3.6-2.ppc
libidn-1.35-1.ppc
less-481-1.ppc
python-2.7.15-5.ppc
git-2.21.0-6.ppc
lynx-2.8.4-2.ppc
AIX-rpm-6.1.8.15-7.ppc
zlib-1.2.11-1.ppc
gmp-6.1.1-1.ppc
ncurses-6.1-1.ppc
xz-libs-5.2.2-2.ppc
glib2-2.48.1-2.ppc
libunistring-0.9.6-2.ppc
gettext-0.19.8-1.ppc
info-6.4-1.ppc
gcc-cpp-8.3.0-1.ppc
unzip-6.0-3.ppc
readline-7.0-1.ppc
gdbm-1.10-1.ppc
openssl-1.1.0g-1withsslv2.ppc
libssh2-1.8.0-1.ppc
vim-common-7.4-4.ppc
libtool-ltdl-2.4.6-2.ppc
openldap-2.4.44-5.ppc
curl-7.64.0-1ldapssl.ppc
bzip2-1.0.6-2.ppc
vim-enhanced-7.4-4.ppc
cpio-2.12-2.ppc
```

4-Now extract node.js tar file in aix and execute this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/nodejs/bin
```

5-Finally its done

```
node app.js
```